# Android Studio gridlayout. Preview and emulator show different outcomes

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I am trying to create a simple grid layout buttons of 2 columns and 4 rows. I want those button to fill their space like it shows in the preview. But the emulator shows different output.

The Preview shows exactly 8 filled buttons saying hello but emulator output shows the buttons on the left size of each box.

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQDJY.png)

[Emulator Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHb9Z.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">


<GridLayout


    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"




    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="4">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"


    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"

        android:orientation="horizontal"

        >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:text="hello"

            />



    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"

            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:text="hello"

                />



        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"

            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:text="hello"

                />



        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"

            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:text="hello"

                />



        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"

            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:text="hello"

                />



        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"

            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:text="hello"

                />



        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"

            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:text="hello"

                />



        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="fill"

            android:orientation="horizontal"

            >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:text="hello"

                />



        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>




</GridLayout>
```

Comment: What Android API version is your emulator running?

Comment: 27. its set to automatically best version.

Comment: add you images and emulator details

Comment: I have added the preview and emulator pictures

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure the issue in that case but i just used the regular grid layout with column and row indication for each button. That did the trick.
Notice that I have layout_column and layout_row to specify where they should stand.

[Solution][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5MAx.png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<GridLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnOrderPreserved="false">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="hello"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="hello"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="hello"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="hello"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="hello"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="2"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="hello"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="hello"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="3"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:text="hello"
        />
```